# How to assign material for an OBJ in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've tried to assign a mtl to my obj model and it doesn't work.

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load("img/website.mtl", function(materials){

    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);

    objLoader.load("img/website.obj", function(mesh){
        mesh.scale.set(0.6,0.6,0.6);
        mesh.rotation.y = 4;
        scene.add(mesh);
    });
});
```

I exported the obj and the mtl files from Cinema 4D. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Try logging the material and mesh to the console to see if it is being loaded and attached correctly.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't clear enough. Does the MTL have images? What are the paths? Do you have image source defined, does it need cors? Is the model all black? Have you defined lights compatible with the mtl definition?